# Divisibility criteria of number 7

Tags: modular-arithmetic

How do I prove the divisiblity criterium of number seven having $a_{n}*10^n + a_{n-1} *10^ {n-1} +  ... + a_3*10^3 + a_2*10^2 + a_1*10 + a_0$

For example, I underestand that in the divisibility criterium of 3 we have to use mod 3 to do it and the expression I wrote before is congruent (in mod 3) $a_{n} + a_{n-1} +  ... + a_3 + a_2 + a_1 + a_0$, but I don't find it for the number seven. I'd appreciate so much a bit of help.

Comment: Please state the divisiblity criterium you have in mind? Or do you mean you want to be given a  divisiblity criterium?

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:**

$10^3\equiv -1 \mod 7$ so you have to cut the number in slices of $3$ digits, starting from the right and check if the alternating sum of the $3$-digit numbers is divisible by $7$.

**Another criterion::**

Write the number $N$ as $10n+a_0,$ $\;0\le a_0\le 9$. $N$ is divisible by $7$ if $n-2a_0$ is.

Answer (score 0):

> Let's assume we want to find a divisibility criterion for $7$ of a given a number $N$
>
> \begin{align*}
>   N=a_{n}\cdot 10^n + a_{n-1} \cdot 10^ {n-1} + \cdots + a_3\cdot 10^3 + a_2\cdot 10^2 + a_1\cdot 10 + a_0
>   \end{align*}
>
> based upon the digits $a_0,a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_n$ of $N$.
>
> In order to do so we apply the modular arithmetic to consecutive powers of $10$ until we find a smallest exponent $n\geq 1$ with $10^{n}\equiv 1 \pmod{7}$.
>
> We obtain
>
> \begin{align*}
>   10&\equiv 3 \pmod{7}\\
>   100&\equiv 10\cdot 10\equiv 3\cdot 3\equiv 2 \pmod{7}\\
>   1000&\equiv 10\cdot 100\equiv 3\cdot2\equiv -1 \pmod{7}\tag{1}\\
>   10000&\equiv 100\cdot 100\equiv 2\cdot 2\equiv -3 \pmod{7}\\
>   100000&\equiv 100\cdot 1000\equiv 2\cdot (-1)\equiv -2 \pmod{7}\\
>   1000000&\equiv 1000\cdot 1000\equiv (-1)\cdot (-1)\equiv 1 \pmod{7}\tag{2}
>   \end{align*}

*Comment:*

- In the last line (2) we obtain a power of $10$ which is congruent $1$ modulo $7$. So, the next power of ten is $10000000 \equiv 10\equiv 3 (\pmod{7})$ and we continue cyclically with the first line.
- In (1) we reduce $1000$ to $-1$ and not to the smallest *positive* value $6$. This way we will find a smaller number than $n$ with the same residue modulo $7$ somewhat easier.

We can now formulate a divisibility criterion based upon the digits of the number $N$:

> The following divisibility criterion for $7$ of a given number $N$ is valid
>   \begin{align*}
>     N&=a_{n}\cdot 10^n + a_{n-1} \cdot 10^ {n-1} +  ... + a_3\cdot 10^3 + a_2\cdot 10^2 + a_1\cdot 10 + a_0\\
>     &\equiv a_0+3a_1+2a_2-a_3-3a_4-2a_5\\
>     &\qquad +a_6+3a_7+2a_8-a_{9}-3a_{10}-2a_{11}\\
>     &\qquad +\cdots  \pmod{7}
>   \end{align*}
>
> For convenience only we started the last expression with $a_0$ and stopped with $\cdots$.
>
> Note the repeating sequence $1,3,2,-1,-3,-2$.

Let's look how to apply this rule. Also note that we can apply the rule more than once, to iterativeley reduce the number under test.

> Example: Check the divisibility of $N=8732576$ with respect to the modulus $7$.
>
> \begin{align*}
> N&=8732576=8\cdot 10^6+7\cdot 10^5+3\cdot 10^4+2\cdot 10^2+5\cdot 10^2+7\cdot 10^1+6\cdot 10^0\\
> &\equiv 6+3\cdot 7+2\cdot 5-2-3\cdot 3-2\cdot 7+8=20\tag{3}\\
> &\equiv 2\cdot 10^1+0\cdot 10^0\\
> &\equiv 0+3\cdot 2=6 \pmod{7}
> \end{align*}
>
> We conclude: $n=8732576$ is not divisible by $7$, since the division gives a remainder $6$.

*Comment:*

- In (3) we apply the divisibility criterion again to $20$. So, we get a chain $N=8732576\rightarrow 20\rightarrow 6$ until we find a non-negative value less than the modulus $7$.